# Cannot pass parameters Dart -> C++ using FFI

Tags: c++, c, dart, dart-ffi

Friends

I am calling a native C++ programme I have written from Dart.

The problem I am having is that the parameters I am passing are not being received on the C++ side.

I have a structure with a buffer pointer and two ints.  A function that takes the parameter and another int.  The function just prints out the parameters.

The structure members are all zero and the passed integer is corrupted.

The C++ code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ParametersTest {
    uint8_t * pixelBuffer;
    int64_t width;
    int64_t height;
};
extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used))
void test_ffi_parameters(struct ParametersTest parameters, int64_t testint){
    printf("In the C++ function. testInt: %d Parameters.width %d Parameters.height %d buffer pointer: %p\n", 
        testint, parameters.width, parameters.height, parameters.pixelBuffer);
    // create_image(parameters.pixelBuffer, parameters.width, parameters.height);
}
```

I load the functions:

```
final DynamicLibrary externalLib = DynamicLibrary.process();

class ParametersTest extends Struct {
  
  external Pointer<Uint8> pixelBuffer;
  
  @Int()
  external int width;
  
  @Int()
  external int height;
}

final void Function(ParametersTest p, int t) testFfiWithParameters = 
       externalLib.
       lookup<NativeFunction<Void
                Function(ParametersTest, Int64)>>('test_ffi_parameters').
                asFunction();
```

And finally I call it:

```
  final pointer = malloc.allocate<ParametersTest>(sizeOf<ParametersTest>());
  final parameters = pointer.ref;
  parameters.width = width;
  parameters.height = height;
  parameters.pixelBuffer = malloc(width * height * 4);
  testFfiWithParameters(parameters, 1234);
```

It is printing out: `In the C++ function. testInt: 1366 Parameters.width 0 Parameters.height 0 buffer pointer: 0x0`

The members of `parameters` are zeroed in the `C++` code (not in `Dart`).  The integer parameter is corrupted.

Comment: Probably not the issue but the type for `width` and `height` are not `Int()` but `Int64()` if it should match your C++ code. The `Int()` are documented as "Typically a signed 32-bit integer." so that would mean your end up with a wrongly sized struct.

Comment: Try passing `pointer` instead of `parameters` having changed the signature to `struct ParametersTest *parameters`, and adjusted the Dart end lookup to match

Comment: A combination of both work: Passing the parameter as a Pointer and `@Int64()` annotations.